# Java Class returns null value

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

Good day people.
I have a problem regarding java classes. I created a java class for executing queries on the database(MySQL) but it always returns **null** value instead of **STRING** here's the code:

Class file:
sql.java

```
public class sql {
Connection conn;
Statement stmt;
ResultSet rs;
String sql;
String result;

public String test(String username){
    try{
        stmt = conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
        sql = "SELECT * from user_account where username='"+username+"'";
        rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
        rs.next();

        result = rs.getString("username");

        return result;
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        return e.getMessage();
    }
}
```

}

main file:

```
public class MainFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    String result;

    public MainFrame() {

      dbConnect connect = new dbConnect();
      connection = connect.connect();
      conn = (Connection) connection[0];
      rs = (ResultSet) connection[1];

      sql query_result = new sql();
      result = query_result.test("test");
      System.out.println(result);
}.....
```

thanks in advance
P.S. the code works if I use the class from the main file. I am using netbeans.

Comment: do you know what `rs.getString("username");` gets you?

Comment: Are you certain that the column name you want back is `"username"`?

Comment: @SamIam, unless the db is doing something very strange with his `WHERE` clause, it should be returning `username` (`"test"`).

Comment: Don't ignore the result of ResultSet.next(). And don't ignore exceptions: let them propagate. And learn about prepared statements to avoid SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Try changing the SQL to `SELECT username from user_account` and your getter to `result = rs.getString(1)` and see what happens.

Comment: Your `conn` variable hasn't been initialized for the `sql` class in the code you have shown.

Comment: You appear to be wonderfully open to SQL Injection.  Please look into using some sort of parameterized query.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(rs.next())
{
   result = rs.getString("username");
System.out.println(result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just figured it out. I added "Connection conn, Resultset rs" as parameters on the class.